# Laravel From RAW Query to Eloquent Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm trying to convert my `Raw query` to an `eloquent query`

You can see here

```
 $data = DB::connection('mysql')->select("SELECT product.id, product.title, product.description, product.content, product.photo, product_per_category.productcategory_id, product.quantity, product.price 
        FROM product LEFT JOIN product_per_category ON product_per_category.product_id = product.id
        WHERE product.deleted = 0 AND product_per_category.deleted = 0 AND productcategory_id = '$id' AND (product.title like '%$keyword%' OR product.content like '%$keyword%' OR product.price like '%$keyword%' OR product.quantity like '%$keyword%')
        
        GROUP BY product.id");
```

I have multiple `WHERE` statement that combines with `AND` & `OR` inside of a parentheses

I just want to know if Im doing this right with my eloquent query like this

```
 $data = DB::table('product')
    ->select('product.id','product.title','product.description','product.content','product.photo','product.quantity','product.price')
    ->join('product_per_category','product_per_category.product_id','=','product.id')
    ->where(['product.deleted' => 0])
    ->where(['product_per_category.deleted' => 0])
    ->where(['product_per_category.productcategory_id' => $id])
    ->orWhere('product.content', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
    ->orWhere('product.title', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
    ->orWhere('product.quantity', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
    ->orWhere('product.price', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
    ->groupBy('product.id')
    ->get();
```

Because I wonder in my query I have `OR` statement inside of a parentheses.

Which I combine them inside of the parentheses to make it only the fields optional with `LIKE` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, but when you need to have conditions between parenthesis, your where() functions should be a callback.

For example `(product.title like '%$keyword%' OR product.content like '%$keyword%' OR product.price like '%$keyword%' OR product.quantity like '%$keyword%')`
would be

```
$query->where(function($subquery) use($keyword) {
    $subquery->where('title', 'like', "%{$keyword}%")
    ->orWhere('content', 'like', "%{$keyword}%");
});
```

This is only a rough example of your requirement, but you should get it.

Just so you know, you can combine almost ALL Eloquent functions.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a **closure** inside the `where` method.
The **closure** will receive a query builder instance which you can use to set the constraints that should be contained within the **parenthesis**.

This is known as `parameter grouping`.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping

Change your statement to this.

```
$data = DB::table('product')
    ->select('product.id','product.title','product.description','product.content','product.photo','product.quantity','product.price')
    ->join('product_per_category','product_per_category.product_id','=','product.id')
    ->where(['product.deleted' => 0])
    ->where(['product_per_category.deleted' => 0])
    ->where(['product_per_category.productcategory_id' => $id])
    ->where(function($query) use($keyword){
        $query->where('product.content', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
              ->orWhere('product.title', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
              ->orWhere('product.quantity', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
              ->orWhere('product.price', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    })
    ->groupBy('product.id')
    ->get();
```